# How to claculate adjacent data with spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava a `RDD`,the `RDD` type is `Tuple2(value,timestamp)`,value is 1 or 0 , timestamp is a sequential, and a variable limitTime=4. When I map the `RDD`, if the value is 1 the output value from current timestamp to (timestamp +limitTime) is 1 ,else current value is 0, I call it is period. But there is a special case，when the value is 1 and its timestamp is in period，then it is ignored, the current value of output is 0

```
input :          (0,0),(1,1),(0,3),(0,5),(0,7),(0,8),(0,10),(1,12),(0,14),(0,15)
expected output :(0,0),(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(0,7),(0,8),(0,10),(1,12),(1,14),(1,15)

special input2:  (0,0),(1,1),(0,3),(1,5),(0,7),(1,8),(0,10),(1,12),(0,14),(0,15)
expected output2:(0,0),(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(0,7),(1,8),(1,10),(1,12),(0,14),(0,15)
this is my try:

 var limitTime=4
    var startTime= -limitTime
  val rdd=sc.parallelize(List((0,0),(1,1),(0,3),(1,5),(0,7),(1,8),(0,10),(1,12),(0,14),(0,15)),4)
      val results=rdd.mapPartitions(parIter => {
        var resultIter = new ArrayBuffer[Tuple2[Int,Int]]()
        while (parIter.hasNext) {
          val iter = parIter.next()
          if(iter._1==1){
            if(iter._2<=startTime+limitTime&&iter._2!=0&&iter._2>=startTime){
              resultIter.append(iter)
            }else{
              resultIter.append(iter)
              startTime=iter._2
            }
          }else{
            if(iter._2<=startTime+limitTime&&iter._2!=0&&iter._2>=startTime){
              resultIter.append((1,iter._2))
            }else{
              resultIter.append(iter)
            }
          }
        }
        resultIter.toIterator
      })
    results.collect().foreach(println)
```

[image]
it's so inefficient，how can I get the same result without array?

Comment: do you want the rule to be performed on each partition or whole dataset at once?

Comment: looking at your first case the limitTime / period looks to be 3. And can you elaborate your second special case?

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan yes, my code have to run in one partition ,it's so inefficient ,Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: Your logic seems to be run on one partition only which is definitely inefficient. And if you run on multiple partitions parallel then you won't have consistent result.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work for both of your cases.

```
var limitTime=3
var first = true
var previousValue = 0
val rdd=sc.parallelize(List((0,0),(1,1),(0,3),(0,5),(0,7),(0,8),(0,10),(1,12),(0,14),(0,15)), 4)
val tempResult = rdd.collect.map(pair => {
  if(first){
    first = false
    previousValue = pair._1
    (pair._1, pair._2)
  }
  else {
    if ((pair._1 == 1 || previousValue == 1) && limitTime > 0) {
      limitTime -= 1
      previousValue = 1
      (1, pair._2)
    }
    else {
      if (limitTime == 0) limitTime = 3
      previousValue = pair._1
      (pair._1, pair._2)
    }
  }
})
tempResult.foreach(print)
```

If it doesn't please let me know

Comment: collect() function may collect data to one partition,it's too inefficient,,Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: collect function will gather all data in driver node and your logic require such step. If you apply the logic in parallel on multiple partitions then you won't be getting expected result.